# android: some doubts about using cache to display images

Tags: android, caching

I am trying to display a lot of images through URL in my application. I found in some website that, we can use cache to display images. And when I used it in my application, I found that the the application cache is increased from 0 KB.

And When I tried to display these images without cahche, the Application heap was grown to 24MB (Max. size) and the application was crashed.

I don't know, whether using cache is a good way. Please tell me. and please tell me the maximum size of cache for one application.

Please help me.. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache is the good way to display image from the web, first you have to download that images into the cache folder of the application and then load images from the cache folder.

Maximum size of application is allowed to upload on market is 50 Mb so you can use Maximum 45 to 48 Mb.

Please copy Image Loader class from [here](http://pastie.org/1868262) its used for display the image from web . Its stored the images into cache folder and show images from the cache folder.